# Pattern for calling WCF service using async/await

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, async-await

I generated a proxy with [task-based operations](https://web.archive.org/web/20131026111135/http://www.guruumeditation.net/async-await-with-wcf).

How should this service be invoked properly (disposing of the `ServiceClient` and the `OperationContext` afterwards) using async/await?

My first attempt was:

```
public async Task<HomeInfo> GetHomeInfoAsync(DateTime timestamp)
{
    using (var helper = new ServiceHelper<ServiceClient, ServiceContract>())
    {
        return await helper.Proxy.GetHomeInfoAsync(timestamp);
    }
}
```

Being `ServiceHelper` a class which creates the `ServiceClient` and the `OperationContextScope` and disposes of them afterwards:

```
try
{
    if (_operationContextScope != null)
    {
        _operationContextScope.Dispose();
    }

    if (_serviceClient != null)
    {
        if (_serviceClient.State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
        {
            _serviceClient.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            _serviceClient.Abort();
        }
    }
}
catch (CommunicationException)
{
    _serviceClient.Abort();
}
catch (TimeoutException)
{
    _serviceClient.Abort();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    _serviceClient.Abort();
    throw;
}
finally
{
    _operationContextScope = null;
    _serviceClient = null;
}
```

However, this failed miserably when calling two services at the same time with the following error: "This OperationContextScope is being disposed on a different thread than it was created."

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontextscope.aspx) says:

> Do not use the asynchronous “await” pattern within a OperationContextScope block. When the continuation occurs, it may run on a different thread and OperationContextScope is thread specific. If you need to call “await” for an async call, use it outside of the OperationContextScope block.

So that's the problem! But, how do we fix it properly?

[This guy did just what MSDN says](http://managedmonkey.blogspot.com/2012/12/operationcontextscope-and-asyncawait.html):

```
private async void DoStuffWithDoc(string docId)
{
   var doc = await GetDocumentAsync(docId);
   if (doc.YadaYada)
   {
        // more code here
   }
}

public Task<Document> GetDocumentAsync(string docId)
{
  var docClient = CreateDocumentServiceClient();
  using (new OperationContextScope(docClient.InnerChannel))
  {
    return docClient.GetDocumentAsync(docId);
  }
}
```

My problem with his code, is that he never calls Close (or Abort) on the ServiceClient.

I also found [a way](https://web.archive.org/web/20130224043420/http://tintoy.snoscillator.net/2012/11/06/async-await-operationcontext-propagatio) of propagating the `OperationContextScope` using a custom `SynchronizationContext`. But, besides the fact that it's a lot of "risky" code, he states that:

> It’s worth noting that it does have a few small issues regarding the disposal of operation-context scopes (since they only allow you to dispose them on the calling thread), but this doesn’t seem to be an issue since (at least according to the disassembly), they implement Dispose() but not Finalize().

So, are we out of luck here? Is there a proven pattern for calling WCF services using async/await AND disposing of BOTH the `ServiceClient` and the `OperationContextScope`? Maybe someone form Microsoft (perhaps guru Stephen Toub :)) can help.

Thanks!

**[UPDATE]**

With a lot of help from user Noseratio, I came up with something that works: do not use `OperationContextScope`. If you are using it for any of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470639/when-should-i-use-operationcontextscope-inside-of-a-wcf-service) reasons, try to find a workaround that fits your scenario. Otherwise, if you really, really, need `OperationContextScope`, you'll have to come up with an implementation of a `SynchronizationContext` that captures it, and that seems [very hard](https://web.archive.org/web/20130224043420/http://tintoy.snoscillator.net/2012/11/06/async-await-operationcontext-propagatio) (if at all possible - there must be a reason why this isn't the default behavior).

So, the full working code is:

```
public async Task<HomeInfo> GetHomeInfoAsync(DateTime timestamp)
{
    using (var helper = new ServiceHelper<ServiceClient, ServiceContract>())
    {
        return await helper.Proxy.GetHomeInfoAsync(timestamp);
    }
}
```

With `ServiceHelper` being:

```
public class ServiceHelper<TServiceClient, TService> : IDisposable
    where TServiceClient : ClientBase<TService>, new()
    where TService : class
{
protected bool _isInitialized;
    protected TServiceClient _serviceClient;

    public TServiceClient Proxy
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_isInitialized)
            {
                Initialize();
                _isInitialized = true;
            }
            else if (_serviceClient == null)
            {
                throw new ObjectDisposedException("ServiceHelper");
            }

            return _serviceClient;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Initialize()
    {
        _serviceClient = new TServiceClient();
    }

    // Implement IDisposable.
    // Do not make this method virtual.
    // A derived class should not be able to override this method.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);

        // Take yourself off the Finalization queue 
        // to prevent finalization code for this object
        // from executing a second time.
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    // Dispose(bool disposing) executes in two distinct scenarios.
    // If disposing equals true, the method has been called directly
    // or indirectly by a user's code. Managed and unmanaged resources
    // can be disposed.
    // If disposing equals false, the method has been called by the 
    // runtime from inside the finalizer and you should not reference 
    // other objects. Only unmanaged resources can be disposed.
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // If disposing equals true, dispose all managed 
        // and unmanaged resources.
        if (disposing)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_serviceClient != null)
                {
                    if (_serviceClient.State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
                    {
                        _serviceClient.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _serviceClient.Abort();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (CommunicationException)
            {
                _serviceClient.Abort();
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                _serviceClient.Abort();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                _serviceClient.Abort();
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                _serviceClient = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the class supports extension; perhaps you need to inherit and provide credentials.

The only possible "gotcha" is that in `GetHomeInfoAsync`, you can't just return the `Task` you get from the proxy (which should seem natural, why create a new `Task` when you already have one). Well, in this case you need to `await` the proxy `Task` and *then* close (or abort) the `ServiceClient`, otherwise you'll be closing it right away after invoking the service (while bytes are being sent over the wire)!

OK, we have a way to make it work, but it'd be nice to get an answer from an authoritative source, as Noseratio states.

Comment: **The environment making calls to the WCF proxy is ASP.NET Web API.**

Comment: I think you need to re-evaluate the need to use async/await and dispose the OperationContextScope. For what I could understand OperationContextScope is a process variable (a static variable, OperationContext.Current implies this) so it's not suitable for parallel service calls with different OperationContextScopes. Because of this async/await is not really compatible with operation context dispose and therefore you are only asking about a hack, which I don't recommend.

Comment: Some info regarding the stack behaviour of the OperantionContextScope http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492085/wcf-operationcontextscope-dispose

Comment: @user823959 Thank you, that's what I ended up doing, not using OperationContextScope. But what happens if you, for example, need to add custom headers? You simply can't take advantage of async/await? I was hoping that someone from Microsoft would acknowledge this as something that could be improved upon, or explain what the approach should be.

Comment: Maybe you can adapt from this http://wcfpro.wordpress.com/2010/11/18/adding-operationcontextscope-to-a-synchronous-methods/

Comment: I haven't completely understood the use of the OperationContext.Current being limited to one thread but my bet would be that you should use a Factory to instantiate clients and OperationContext's. With a Factory we probably would be able to define one OperationContext for all Clients that require the same cookie (assuming that the cookie doesn't update with every service invocation) all would have better performance (less client and operation context instantiations).

Comment: @user823959 That seems promising, I'll look into it and try to adapt it to async/await when I get the chance (I'm on my phone right now). And your idea of a factory sounds interesting, I'll write some code and run some stress tests with a couple hundred clients to see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: Some interesting further discussion about this is [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/558df0bf-4cac-47a6-9cdc-9f0d4f8dd534/alternative-to-the-operationcontext-when-using-asyncawait).

Comment: @Noseratio Rewriting, at IL level, the state machine the compiler generates when using async/await, looks like a fun challenge, and kudos to Tersius if he managed to hack it right; but it's way too risky for production, at least for me. I really laughed when I read Diana's post, talk about Plagiarism! haha.

Comment: @Gabriel, hope you haven't lost interest in this :) [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20993007/1768303) is some new related development.

Comment: @Noseratio, I haven't lost interest at all; in fact, I'm about to start a project in which we have to call existing WCF services which rely on data passed through OperationContextScope, and I'd really like to take advantage of async/await on the Web API client. Thanks for the update, I read (and favorited) your post and everything you linked. If Stephen's right I guess I'm not going to be forced to abandon asynchrony in this new project (unless we rewrite the services so they don't depend on the context; this should be standard practice for any new project). I'll keep myself posted.

Comment: @Gabriel, getting back to it, what do you think about this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22753055/1768303 ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think a feasible solution might be to use a **custom awaiter** to flow the new operation context via `OperationContext.Current`. The [implementation of `OperationContext`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/OperationContext.cs) itself doesn't appear to require thread affinity. Here is the pattern:

```
async Task TestAsync()
{
    using(var client = new WcfAPM.ServiceClient())
    using (var scope = new FlowingOperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
    {
        await client.SomeMethodAsync(1).ContinueOnScope(scope);
        await client.AnotherMethodAsync(2).ContinueOnScope(scope);
    }
}
```

Here is the implementation of `FlowingOperationContextScope` and `ContinueOnScope` (only slightly tested):

```
public sealed class FlowingOperationContextScope : IDisposable
{
    bool _inflight = false;
    bool _disposed;
    OperationContext _thisContext = null;
    OperationContext _originalContext = null;

    public FlowingOperationContextScope(IContextChannel channel):
        this(new OperationContext(channel))
    {
    }

    public FlowingOperationContextScope(OperationContext context)
    {
        _originalContext = OperationContext.Current;
        OperationContext.Current = _thisContext = context;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (_inflight || OperationContext.Current != _thisContext)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            _disposed = true;
            OperationContext.Current = _originalContext;
            _thisContext = null;
            _originalContext = null;
        }
    }

    internal void BeforeAwait()
    {
        if (_inflight)
            return;
        _inflight = true;
        // leave _thisContext as the current context
   }

    internal void AfterAwait()
    {
        if (!_inflight)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        _inflight = false;
        // ignore the current context, restore _thisContext
        OperationContext.Current = _thisContext;
    }
}

// ContinueOnScope extension
public static class TaskExt
{
    public static SimpleAwaiter<TResult> ContinueOnScope<TResult>(this Task<TResult> @this, FlowingOperationContextScope scope)
    {
        return new SimpleAwaiter<TResult>(@this, scope.BeforeAwait, scope.AfterAwait);
    }

    // awaiter
    public class SimpleAwaiter<TResult> :
        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.INotifyCompletion
    {
        readonly Task<TResult> _task;

        readonly Action _beforeAwait;
        readonly Action _afterAwait;

        public SimpleAwaiter(Task<TResult> task, Action beforeAwait, Action afterAwait)
        {
            _task = task;
            _beforeAwait = beforeAwait;
            _afterAwait = afterAwait;
        }

        public SimpleAwaiter<TResult> GetAwaiter()
        {
            return this;
        }

        public bool IsCompleted
        {
            get 
            {
                // don't do anything if the task completed synchronously
                // (we're on the same thread)
                if (_task.IsCompleted)
                    return true;
                _beforeAwait();
                return false;
            }

        }

        public TResult GetResult()
        {
            return _task.Result;
        }

        // INotifyCompletion
        public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
        {
            _task.ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                _afterAwait();
                continuation();
            },
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
            SynchronizationContext.Current != null ?
                TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() :
                TaskScheduler.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm impressed!
I just tested this a bit and it seems to work fine: I didn't get any `OperationContextScope is being disposed on a different thread than it was created` exceptions, and I was able to pass context info and retrieve it server-side through `OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders` (`ClientCredentials` worked OK too, FWIW).
I'm gonna take some time to wrap my head around your solution, @noseratio :) Can you come up with edge cases or things we should consider before using this in production code?
Thanks!

Comment: @Gabriel, I think we'd need to add something like  `SynchronizationContext.Current != null? TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(): TaskScheduler.Current` to `ContinueWith` above, to make sure we restore `AspNetSynchronizationContext`.

Comment: Something like [this](https://gist.github.com/gabrielmaldi/14b410ceafb084e2eafa)? I tested that and it's still working.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer. @Noseratio, if you think about any improvements that could be made, just edit it and I'll update my code. Some time from now (sadly, no less than a month) I'll come back with results regarding load tests I'll have to run before I can ship this to production. Let's hope everything works the way it should :) Thanks for your help and work with this!

Comment: Thanks @Gabriel, I've included the `FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` update in the code above. Fingers crossed we haven't missed anything so it will work as expected :) I'll too come back here if I find anything.

Comment: This is a very useful answer! I found one possible improvement, however. I used this in a nested context and found that a Boolean value for _inflight caused `InvalidOperationException`. Instead, you can use an _inflight counter of type `int`, increment on `BeforeAwait`, and decrement on `AfterAwait`.

Comment: This is great!  Saved me from the brink of a total redesign.  Thank you!

Comment: This is awesome, solve my problem with accessing HttpResponseMessageProperty within the current OperationContext. Would like to fully understand what the classes are doing. Can anyone point me towards some documentation to explain how the awaiter is working?

Answer (score 10):

Simple way is to move the await outside the using block

```
public Task<Document> GetDocumentAsync(string docId)
{
    var docClient = CreateDocumentServiceClient();
    using (new OperationContextScope(docClient.InnerChannel))
    {
        var task = docClient.GetDocumentAsync(docId);
    }
    return await task;
}
```

Comment: This is a really easy solution to the problem

Comment: Is there a reason that this would not work? It even states that in the MSDN snippet quoted in the question: 'If you need to call “await” for an async call, use it outside of the OperationContextScope block.'

Answer (score 2):

I decide to write my own code that helps with this, posting in case this helps anyone.  Seems to be a little less to go wrong (unforeseen races etc) vs the SimpleAwaiter implementation above but you be the judge:

```
public static class WithOperationContextTaskExtensions
{
    public static ContinueOnOperationContextAwaiter<TResult> WithOperationContext<TResult>(this Task<TResult> @this, bool configureAwait = true)
    {
        return new ContinueOnOperationContextAwaiter<TResult>(@this, configureAwait);
    }

    public static ContinueOnOperationContextAwaiter WithOperationContext(this Task @this, bool configureAwait = true)
    {
        return new ContinueOnOperationContextAwaiter(@this, configureAwait);
    }

    public class ContinueOnOperationContextAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
    {
        private readonly ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter _awaiter;
        private OperationContext _operationContext;

        public ContinueOnOperationContextAwaiter(Task task, bool continueOnCapturedContext = true)
        {
            if (task == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("task");

            _awaiter = task.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext).GetAwaiter();
        }

        public ContinueOnOperationContextAwaiter GetAwaiter() { return this; }

        public bool IsCompleted { get { return _awaiter.IsCompleted; } }

        public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
        {
            _operationContext = OperationContext.Current;
            _awaiter.OnCompleted(continuation);
        }

        public void GetResult()
        {
            OperationContext.Current = _operationContext;
            _awaiter.GetResult();
        }
    }

    public class ContinueOnOperationContextAwaiter<TResult> : INotifyCompletion
    {
        private readonly ConfiguredTaskAwaitable<TResult>.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter _awaiter;
        private OperationContext _operationContext;

        public ContinueOnOperationContextAwaiter(Task<TResult> task, bool continueOnCapturedContext = true)
        {
            if (task == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("task");

            _awaiter = task.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext).GetAwaiter();
        }

        public ContinueOnOperationContextAwaiter<TResult> GetAwaiter() { return this; }

        public bool IsCompleted { get { return _awaiter.IsCompleted; } }

        public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
        {
            _operationContext = OperationContext.Current;
            _awaiter.OnCompleted(continuation);
        }

        public TResult GetResult()
        {
            OperationContext.Current = _operationContext;
            return _awaiter.GetResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage (a little manual and nesting is untested...):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Make a call to the service
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action"></param>
    /// <param name="endpoint"> </param>
    public async Task<ResultCallWrapper<TResult>> CallAsync<TResult>(Func<T, Task<TResult>> action, EndpointAddress endpoint)
    {
        using (ChannelLifetime<T> channelLifetime = new ChannelLifetime<T>(ConstructChannel(endpoint)))
        {
            // OperationContextScope doesn't work with async/await
            var oldContext = OperationContext.Current;
            OperationContext.Current = new OperationContext((IContextChannel)channelLifetime.Channel);

            var result = await action(channelLifetime.Channel)
                .WithOperationContext(configureAwait: false);

            HttpResponseMessageProperty incomingMessageProperty = (HttpResponseMessageProperty)OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name];

            string[] keys = incomingMessageProperty.Headers.AllKeys;
            var headersOrig = keys.ToDictionary(t => t, t => incomingMessageProperty.Headers[t]);

            OperationContext.Current = oldContext;

            return new ResultCallWrapper<TResult>(result, new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>(headersOrig));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Async flow is supported from .Net 4.6.2.

We have an ASP.Net WebApi application running on .Net 4.6 where we used the accepted answer. `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` caused deadlock issues when the current synchronization context is `AspNetSynchronizationContext`.

I believe the continuation task was queued after the actual task, causing the actual task is waiting on the continuation whereas the continuation task must run to complete the actual task. i.e. tasks are both waiting on each other.

So I fixed the issue by changing using continuation task to use TaskAwaiter. See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lucian/2012/12/11/how-to-write-a-custom-awaiter/

Comment: Great! Thanks for contributing to this open issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while on this one, but I'll chime in with my own home-baked solution.

If one doesn't mind doing without `OperationContextScope`, one might consider something along these lines:

**Extension methods**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Intexx.ServiceModel
{
    public static class WcfExtensions
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public static void Call<TChannel>(this TChannel Client, Action<TChannel> Method) where TChannel : ICommunicationObject
        {
            try
            {
                Method.Invoke(Client);
            }
            finally
            {
                Cleanup(Client);
            }
        }

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public static TResult Call<TChannel, TResult>(this TChannel Client, Func<TChannel, TResult> Method) where TChannel : ICommunicationObject
        {
            try
            {
                return Method.Invoke(Client);
            }
            finally
            {
                Cleanup(Client);
            }
        }

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public async static Task CallAsync<TChannel>(this TChannel Client, Func<TChannel, Task> Method) where TChannel : ICommunicationObject
        {
            try
            {
                await Method.Invoke(Client);
            }
            finally
            {
                Cleanup(Client);
            }
        }

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public async static Task<TResult> CallAsync<TChannel, TResult>(this TChannel Client, Func<TChannel, Task<TResult>> Method) where TChannel : ICommunicationObject
        {
            try
            {
                return await Method.Invoke(Client);
            }
            finally
            {
                Cleanup(Client);
            }
        }

        private static void Cleanup<TChannel>(TChannel Client) where TChannel : ICommunicationObject
        {
            try
            {
                if (Client.IsNotNull)
                {
                    if (Client.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
                        Client.Abort();
                    else
                        Client.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Client.Abort();

                if (!ex is CommunicationException && !ex is TimeoutException)
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
            }

            finally
            {
                Client = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Client class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Reader
{
    public class Client
    {
        public static CemReaderClient Create()
        {
            Tuple<Channels.Binding, EndpointAddress, double> oService;

            try
            {
                oService = Main.Services(typeof(ICemReader));
                return new CemReaderClient(oService.Item1, oService.Item2);
            }
            catch (KeyNotFoundException ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage** *(in VB, as the code wouldn't convert)*

```
Using oReader As Reader.CemReaderClient = Reader.Client.Create
  If oReader.IsNotNothing Then
    Dim lIsReading = Await oReader.CallAsync(Function(Reader As Reader.CemReaderClient)
                                               Me.ConfigFilePath = If(Me.ConfigFilePath, Reader.GetConfigFilePath)
                                               Me.BackupDrive = If(Me.BackupDrive, Reader.GetBackupDrive)
                                               Me.SerialPort = If(Me.SerialPort, Reader.GetSerialPort)
                                               Me.LogFolder = If(Me.LogFolder, Reader.GetLogFolder)

                                               Return Reader.GetIsReadingAsync
                                             End Function)
  End If
End Using
```

I've had this running reliably in production under frequency loads of around 15 calls/sec on the client side (that's as fast as serial processing would allow). That was on a single thread, though—this hasn't been rigorously tested for thread safety. YMMV.

In my case, I decided to roll the extension methods into their own private NuGet package. The whole construct has turned out to be pretty handy.

This will have to be reevaluated, of course, if `OperationContextScope` ever ends up being needed.

The bit with the `Tuple` in the `Client` class is for Service Discovery support. If anyone would like to see that code as well, give a shout and I'll update my answer.

Comment: This looks great!

Comment: @gabrielmaldi ~ It gets better. I've put together another private package for easy creation of TopShelf services; that package consumes this one. So with just a few lines of code, I can spin up a Windows Service that also includes WCF discoverable self-hosting. It's because of things like these that we love what we do.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit confused, I found this Blog : [Task-based asynchronous operation in WCF](https://rashimuddin.wordpress.com/2013/05/07/task-based-asynchronous-operation-in-wcf/)

There this is a async wcf communication:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMessage
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<string> GetMessages(string msg);
}

public class MessageService : IMessage
{
   async Task<string> IMessage.GetMessages(string msg)
   {
      var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                     {
                                         Thread.Sleep(10000);
                                         return "Return from Server : " + msg;
                                     });
     return await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
   }
}
```

Client:

```
var client = new Proxy("BasicHttpBinding_IMessage");
       var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => client.GetMessages("Hello"));
       var str = await task;
```

So is this also a good way??

Comment: This looks like it can work, but it also is a lot of effort for nothing. The WCF proxy generator automatically creates `*Async` calls for us, so there's no need to build Async/Await directly into our service methods. (As a side note, this code doesn't follow the standard naming convention of suffixing async methods with `*Async`.) Here's [one possible approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57487899/722393).

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same issue, however it dawned on me that I didn't need to use async/await at all.

Since you are not post processing the result, there is no need to wait for the reply.  If you do need to process the result, just use the old fashion TPL continuation.

```
public Task<MyDomainModel> GetHomeInfoAsync(DateTime timestamp)
{
    using (var helper = new ServiceHelper<ServiceClient, ServiceContract>())
    {
        return helper.Proxy.GetHomeInfoAsync(timestamp).ContinueWith(antecedent=>processReplay(antecedent.Result));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, @khoi-pham. However, not using `async/await` (this of course includes just using `ContinueWith`) causes a `CommunicationObjectAbortedException` since we are disposing of the resources immediately: as soon as we `return` the `Task` we leave the `using` statement, and this happens before the service invocation completes.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this helps, but after seeing this question on my search to answer the same question, I came upon [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/11/13/simplified-asynchronous-programming-model-in-wcf-with-async-await.aspx).

Leading from that, I should think your code should look something like this:

```
public async Task<HomeInfo> GetHomeInfoAsync(DateTime timestamp)
{
    using (var client = CreateDocumentServiceClient())
    {
        await client.BeginGetHomeInfoAsync(timestamp);
    }
}
```

I realise my answer comes rather late :P but it might help someone else.

Comment: Thank you for your help, @TMVector, but I think that code sample works only because `CreateDocumentServiceClient()` is not using `OperationContextScope`; otherwise, it would fail with "This OperationContextScope is being disposed on a different thread than it was created."