# How to use only one Connection to execute multiple commands and queries?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core-mvc, npgsql, linqpad

Here is [Complete code link](https://codeshare.io/9OVXw7)

I wanted to use only npgsql connection to execute multiple queries, instead of using multiple connections as shown below:

```
class TransactionAccess
{
    private const string connString = "Host=localhost;Username=postgres;Password=1234;Database=ExpenseManagerDB";
        public static void GetExpense(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
        {
            var Expense = connection.Query<TransactionView>(@"SELECT SUM(t.amount) as Expense 
                                                        FROM transaction AS t 
                                                        INNER JOIN account AS a ON t.account_id = a.account_id 
                                                        WHERE t.date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate AND a.type = 'expense'", new { startDate, endDate });
            Expense.Dump();
        }
    }

    public static void GetFilteredTransactionsList(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
        {
            var filteredTransactions = connection.Query<TransactionView>(@"SELECT a.account_name, a.account_id, a.type, DATE(t.date), t.transaction_id, t.amount, t.note 
                                                                       FROM transaction AS t 
                                                                       INNER JOIN account AS a ON t.account_id = a.account_id 
                                                                       WHERE t.date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
                                                                       ORDER BY t.date", new { startDate, endDate });
            filteredTransactions.Dump();
        }
    }
}
```

Instead, I want to do something like this:

```
    class TransactionAccess
{
    private const string connString = "Host=localhost;Username=postgres;Password=1234;Database=ExpenseManagerDB";
    using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
{
public static void GetExpense(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
            var Expense = connection.Query<TransactionView>(@"SELECT SUM(t.amount) as Expense 
                                                        FROM transaction AS t 
                                                        INNER JOIN account AS a ON t.account_id = a.account_id 
                                                        WHERE t.date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate AND a.type = 'expense'", new { startDate, endDate });
            Expense.Dump();
        
    }

    public static void GetFilteredTransactionsList(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
            var filteredTransactions = connection.Query<TransactionView>(@"SELECT a.account_name, a.account_id, a.type, DATE(t.date), t.transaction_id, t.amount, t.note 
                                                                       FROM transaction AS t 
                                                                       INNER JOIN account AS a ON t.account_id = a.account_id 
                                                                       WHERE t.date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
                                                                       ORDER BY t.date", new { startDate, endDate });
            filteredTransactions.Dump();
    
    }
}
```

like this, using a single connection to execute multiple queries and methods/ How can I do that?

If anyone can help a bit more please edit the code accordingly in [here](https://codeshare.io/9OVXw7)

Comment: with async function calls, check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/41760048/125032

Comment: @hazimdikenli: In that solution also he is using multiple connections, but I wanted to use only one connection

Comment: Any reason why you want to use one connection? Are you aware of .Net's connection pool?

Comment: How did you come with the conclusion that he is using multiple connections, I see a single context, and a context works with a single connection, as result it is using a single connection. I think what you are asking and what you need are completely different?

Comment: you should store the `connection` object in your class level member variable after opening the connection once. You cannot span the using block across methods like you've shown. this is more like understand of using member variables of C# class, than to do with postgres.

Answer (score 0):

You can only run a single statement on one database connection at the same time (unless you are using cursors, but then the same holds for the `FETCH` statements). So if you want several threads to issue database statements independently, you either have to serialize access to the database connection or you have to use multiple connections.

Answer (score 0):

Create a member variable for your `TransactionAccess` class, named as `conn` of type `NpgsqlConnection`. And also make your class implement the `IDisposable` interface.

You should open the connection only in the constructor of this class and initialize it like below,

```
  conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
```

The other member functions like `GetExpense()` etc, can use the `conn` member to execute the queries as per your business logic.

And in your class' `Dispose` method, remember to close the connection, like so,

```
 public void Dispose()
 {
    conn.Close();
 }
```